# Factorize a matrix that is associated to an image with RGB code

Tags: image-processing

I have this image data and size:

```
image1 = Import[StringJoin["https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3463/3823583611_c80bf5a375_b.jpg"]];
Data1 = ImageData[image1];
size1 = ImageDimensions[image1];
```

And the code that factorizes the matrix with RGB code:

```
SeparateMatrixRGB[image_, size_, Data_] := 
 Module[{RData, GData, BData},
  RData = 
   Table[Table[Data[[i, j, 1]], {i, 1, size[[2]]}], {j, 1, size[[1]]}];
  GData = 
   Table[Table[Data[[i, j, 2]], {i, 1, size[[2]]}], {j, 1, size[[1]]}];
  BData = 
   Table[Table[Data[[i, j, 3]], {i, 1, size[[2]]}], {j, 1, size[[1]]}];
  Return[List[RData, GData, BData]]
  ]
```

This code works but when I try to put my image in black and white with this:

```
image1=ColorConvert[image1,"Grayscale"]
```

it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas of what I have to do?

Comment: First, you can achieve the separation directly and faster using `{RData, GData, BData} = Flatten[Data1, {3}];` . Second, once you convert the image to grayscale you don't have RGB components any more; instead each pixel is described by a single number indicating its gray level. Your function, or my proposal, would not work on that because the structure of the `ImageData` output is different, and also because what you are trying to do does not make sense on that input.

Comment: Why not just use `ImageData/@ColorSeparate[image1]` ?

Comment: @flinty and gives my image in black and white?

Comment: @MarcoB I need to program by myself a RGB for a project, so I can't just use {RData, GData, BData} = Flatten[Data1, {3}];...

Comment: @John Why not? I don't understand. It gives the same exact result of your SeparateMatrix. You could also wrap it in a function: `SeparateMatrixRGB[image_, size_, Data_] := {RData, GData, BData} =  Flatten[Data, {3}]`.

Comment: @But if I have to put my image in black and white I ca't do that right?

Comment: @MarcoB I think `Transpose[Data1, {2, 3, 1}]` will be quicker.

Comment: If you want a grayscale image in RGB color space you can simply convert it back again: `ColorConvert[ColorConvert[image1, "Grayscale"], "RGB"]`